# Safari shows white space under my image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I can't figure out why Safari is adding a white space to the bottom of the image on this website I am working on.

It renders correctly in Firefox and Chrome. The image should be fixed against the bottom of the page including when resized.

Here's some html

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">


    <div class="span12">

        <div id="headImage">

            <img class="center fit" src="images/Dale2.png" onmousedown='return false;' ondragstart='return false;'>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- ./container -->


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function set_body_height() { // set body height = window height
            $('body').height($(window).height());
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).bind('resize', set_body_height);
            set_body_height();
        });


        $('img').bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
            return false;
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".center").hover(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/DaleBlurWithText.png");
            }, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/Dale2.png");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

and the CSS

```
body {
 max-height:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 padding-top: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navbar {
 background: white;
 border: none;
}

.navbar-brand nav navbar-nav {
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar navbar-collapse {
text-align: center;
}

* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.fit {
/* set relative picture size */

max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}

.center {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 bottom-fixed: 0;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reduced test case. See https://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/ for more info.

Comment: Just curious...what's this? `bottom-fixed: 0;`

Comment: @Paulie_D To fix the image to the bottom but I assume if you asked what it was, it doesn't do this haha

Comment: You can set the body's height to the window's height by giving `html` and `body` a height of `100%`. There's no need for JavaScript.

Comment: @zeroflagL Cool thank you, I've changed that and removed the javascript but I 've still got a small white gap under the image in safari albeit is smaller now since I changed that.

Comment: @FrasKyl Not sure, but try adding `line-height: 0` to `.center` rule. Sorry I don't have Safari to test.

Comment: Hey @SafeerHussain I gave that a shot but it didn't seem to get rid of the white space, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my css for my .center class to as follows and it solved the issue:

```
.center {
    display: block;
    position:fixed;

    /* Center the image */
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    /* set relative picture size */ 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting your image to `display: block`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes it does. It might not the the answer the requester is looking for, but in my experience this has always fixed my "white space underneath my image" issues. It's been a known solution for several years.

Comment: Hey @ded, thanks for the suggestion but my original Css I already had display:block, the answer I've posted solved my issue. Not sure if it will help others but some the trick for me. Thanks again for taking the time to answer

Comment: This didn't help, but the hint to start fixing the display was perfect with my image proglems. Thanks